# Как исправить ошибку при записи в файл 1С?

Tags: 1с

Я сделал процедуру, которая при записи пользователя создает файл и записывает в него время записи

```
НовоеВремя = Формат(ТекущаяДата(), "ДФ='ЧЧммсс'");
Файл = Новый ЗаписьТекста("D:\" + НовоеВремя + ".txt");
Файл.ЗаписатьСтроку(НовоеВремя);
Файл.Закрыть();
```

Но почему-то при записи вылетает ошибка

```
Ошибка доступа к файлу 'D:\194111.txt'
{Справочник.Пользователи.Форма.ФормаЭлемента.Форма(1889)}:  Записать(ПараметрыЗаписи);
{mngcore/MessageBox.clf(4)}:    Close(-100);

по причине:
Ошибка при выполнении обработчика - 'ПриЗаписи'
по причине:
Ошибка доступа к файлу 'D:\194111.txt'
по причине:
Ошибка доступа к файлу 'D:\194111.txt'
```

С чем это может быть связано и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Почитай в СП о четвертом параметре "`<Дописывать>`" метода-конструктора "`Новый ЗаписьТекста`". Он по умолчанию `Ложь`, и судя по всему, в таком случае ждет открытие существующего файла, а не создание нового.

Comment: @Sagittarius пробовал заранее создать файл, чтобы туда записать, но тоже не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно проблема связана с правами пользователя; Запустите 1С от имени администратора и попробуйте *Запись* в файл.

Либо создайте новую папку на диске D и предоставьте к ней доступ пользователю операционной системы под которым работаем в момент записи файла ...

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
НовоеВремя = Формат(ТекущаяДата(), "ДФ='ЧЧммсс'");

Текст = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;
Текст.ДобавитьСтроку(НовоеВремя);

ИмяФайла = СтрШаблон("D:\%1.txt", НовоеВремя);

Текст.Записать(ИмяФайла);
```